# Redirect from non-existent subdomains is correct?

Tags: seo, subdomain, canonical-url

Search engines recorded referrals from links like this: `http://subdomain1.example.com`, `http://subdomain2.example.com`. Subdomain pages display the contents of main domain pages but subdomains do not exist. CMS writes canonical link with subdomain address for subdomain page and with domain address for main domain page.

Is the correct solution for SEO to set 301 redirect from non-existent subdomains on main domain or can I just rewrite `href` attribute in canonical link before output for subdomain pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the correct canonical URL in the `link` element should be sufficient (although you might need to verify these "non-existent" subdomains in Google Search Console?), however, it would be preferable to set a 301 redirect which will catch users as well and prevent them linking to the wrong domain, etc.

This sort of redirect can be (should be) included as part of your canonical (www / non-www) redirect.

For example, to redirect all requests that are not for your canonical domain (eg. `example.com`) to your canonical domain then you can do something like the following in your server config, or .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=example.com
RewriteRule .* http://example.com/$0 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I know that these subdomains on the server does not exist. But search engines somewhere finds links with subdomains pointing to different pages of the site.

Comment: Setting up a _redirect_ would probably be the only way to resolve these erroneous links being reported. Do you see many different subdomains? Or just a few? You could verify these subdomains in Google Search Console (formerly Webmaster Tools) to find out where these links are coming from. You say you are seeing "referrals" from those subdomains... for which domain are you seeing these referrals?, ie. what is the target?

Comment: I see many different subdomains. More than one hundred.

Comment: Do you have any legitimate subdomains? That many erroneous subdomains sounds like a misconfiguration somewhere - unless perhaps subdomains are part of your URL model?

Comment: No. Multiple sites on the same VPS. But there is no subdomain.

Comment: The fact that these non-existent subdomains even resolve implies you have a "wildcard subdomain" `CNAME`/`A` record in your domains DNS zone? Normally these subdomains would not resolve unless explicitly configured. However, you shouldn't remove this now since you might lose legitimate traffic. You will need to redirect to your canonical domain.

Comment: These addresses with subdomains are not loaded in the search index. But yandex metrika detects transitions to these adress. For example: http://mdoy52.my_real_domain/my_real_page. After a search by keyword mdoy52 i found several sites with working subdomain mdoy52, but their real domain doesn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31234/discussion-between-ivanmalenko-and-w3d).